# How to duplicate array within same array x times?

Tags: arrays, list, kotlin

So, I have made function that return publicKey and I need to duplicate it `x` times for later use. 
For example: `publicKey: [76, 152, 93, 102, 145, 181]` and I need to duplicate it `3` times, so the end result should be `[76, 152, 93, 102, 145, 181, 76, 152, 93, 102, 145, 181, 76, 152, 93, 102, 145, 181]`.
I have tried using var list3 = publicKey*x, but as you can imagine, it didn't work..

```
fun getPublicKey(privateKey: ArrayList<BigInteger>, 
                 birthDay: BigInteger, 
                 primNumb: BigInteger): ArrayList<BigInteger> {
    val inversMod = birthDay.modInverse(primNumb)
    //println(inversMod)
    val publicKey: ArrayList<BigInteger> = ArrayList()
    for (keyValue in privateKey){
        val pagaiduValue = (keyValue * inversMod).mod(primNumb)
        //println("($keyValue * $inversMod) mod $primNumb = $pagaiduValue")
        publicKey.add(pagaiduValue)
    }
    return publicKey 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a short and simple solution:

```
inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.times(count: Int) = (1..count).flatMap { this }
```

Can be used like this:

```
val numbers = listOf(1, 2, 3)
val result = numbers.times(5)
println(result)                 // [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

---

Perhaps the naming could use some work, `times` could also be assumed to have the effect of multiplying each element by a given number, `repeat` could be a better alternative. Also, you might wanna define it on `Array<T>` and the primitive array types (`IntArray`, etc) as well.